# Installing modules in Python 3.5.2 error

Tags: python, pip

Sorry if I will sound really dumb but I get an error while trying to install python 3.5.2 modules using pip. The whole error screen is the following:

[image: The error from the command line]

The same thing happens when I try to update pip and as far as I understand pip comes by default with python 3.5. What I am missing or is there a simpler way to get modules to work?

Running windows 10

Also I am new to python

Comment: Open the command line terminal as administrator and run the install command again.

Comment: Thank you so much! The most annoying things are the simplest ones

Comment: In the future copy and paste your traceback or terminal text directly into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have administrator privileges? Looks like you don't have privileges to access files

Comment: That's the problem. Thanks